# Relationship between derivative of a function at two points and the function itself.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Suppose I am given a function $u$ defined in an interval $[a,b]$. Suppose I know $u'(a)$, $u'(b)$ and $u((a+b)/2)$. Is it possible to determine the values of $u(a)$ and $u(b)$ using the given information.

Note: In the solution of this exercise it states that $$u(a)=u((a+b)/2)+(a-b)(u'(a)+u'(b))/4$$ and similarly $$u(b)=u((a+b)/2)-(a-b)(u'(a)+u'(b))/4$$

How exactly was this derived? Is there an underlying theorem that was used and I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

No, the given information is not sufficient.

The given formula is not correct.

As a counter example consider $$u(x)=\sin(x)$$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$

$$\sin(0)=\sin(\pi /2)+\pi [1-1]/4 \implies 0=1$$ which is obviously wrong.